# Ubuntu 18.04 not working with Intel Integrated Graphics

Tags: drivers, system-installation, graphics, intel

I'm trying to install 18.04 using my iGPU with the intention of using my dedicated GPU for GPU passthrough. Currently I'm just at the stage of trying to get Ubuntu just to work with my iGPU on the i5 6600K.

First time round I installed with just my RX480 as my primary gpu, the install went smoothly and everything was fine. I changed my primary gpu to the iGPU and instead of the Ubuntu splash screen I instead see the checks being  done in the background, the screen flashes 4 times or so and then I get to the login screen (even though I had enabled auto-login). I enter the password, it looks like it is about to take me to the desktop, but it puts me back to the login screen.

I then thought that maybe I needed to install Ubuntu with the iGPU as the primary device, the first time round I started getting errors about holding bad packages and errors writing to virtual memory. So I tried again, this time removing the overclock from my CPU thinking it might be that. The install went perfectly until I had to reboot, then I got taken to the login screen but the screen is all torn and everything is illegible. I switched the primary device back to the dedicated GPU, and it boots up perfectly and the image is displayed properly.

I have tried adding `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1920*1080` to my grub file which did not work and I tried updating `xserver-xorg-video-intel` but was told I had the latest version and I'm struggling to work out what is wrong and just getting ready to give up on this project.

If it helps at all my system specs are:

i5 6600k

16GB DDR4

RX 480 8GB

MSI Z170 Krait Gaming 3x

If anyone can help I'll love you forever and if you need me to provide any info please let me know what you need.

Comment: My understanding is that GPU passthrough is a fairly cutting edge thing at the moment. These guys seem to be pushing this forward with good success: https://forum.level1techs.com/search?q=gpu%20passthrough

Comment: @hmayag Yeah, I plan to follow their guide once I can get the integrated GPU working with the OS first as that is causing me the most trouble right now.

Comment: I have the same exact problem that I described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1062614/29595) yesterday

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference but I use `1920x1080` not `1920*1080`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix it _does_ make a difference ! Indeed it should be the former one. (`1920x1080`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your first wish is to run on the IGD exclusively, then sort the remaining issues.  The following steps should achieve the first goal to increasing degrees of thoroughness.

Check for improvement after each step, and stop when it works.  Don't needlessly blacklist the kernel modules, as this could mean the discrete card won't be powered down. In fact, you may want to swap steps 3 and 4.

**1. Configure Xorg to prefer the Intel**

Create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf` (this may require `mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`), containing:

```
Section "OutputClass"
   Identifier "Intel"
   MatchDriver "i915"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

**2. Disable modeswitching out of IGD**

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `xdg.force_integrated=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. When done, run `sudo update-grub` before rebooting.

**3. Blacklist the `nouveau` kernel driver**

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` to  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. When done, run `sudo update-grub` before rebooting.  (For AMD blacklist `radeon`, `amdgpu`, etc..)

**4. Uninstall the Xorg nouveau driver**

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau  # or radeon, amdgpu ...
```

This will trigger removal of the `xserver-xorg-video-all` meta-package, which by default is installed. That is alright, but you may want to keep `xserver-xorg-video-intel` installed (but see update below):

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-video-all
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

**Update 2019** the package description for `xserver-xorg-video-intel` now recommends against installing the package.  It should only be needed on old (pre 2007) hardware.

---

**Note:** this is an edited copy of my answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1058758/134479), which may have useful pointers for your follow-on steps, as it is about resolving issues with the discrete card.

Comment: You sir, are a goddamn legend. The first solution worked like a charm and now I have other solutions to fall back on if this fails.

Comment: Great to hear! On AskUbuntu, don't use the comments to say "thanks". That's what the upvote and accept buttons are for.

Comment: Tried this solution in relation to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1078607/is-there-a-way-to-force-x-to-use-intel-integrated-graphics-while-mining-ethereum) and it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. This stopped the cursor flickering in my browser (Brave) on Dell XPS 13 9370.

Comment: thank you, worked like a charm

Comment: This worked to enable gpu like I wanted but it created flicker issues. I see regions of black or white on browser and apps like teams, etc

Answer (score 0):

The above solution didn't work in my case, I solved the problem by purging the nux-tools:

```
sudo apt purge nux-tools
```