# ubuntu 18.04 does not recognize intel graphics card after update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics

Just did a regular ubuntu update on a laptop. 
Now in About>Details it says

Graphics: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)

It said "Intel Graphics (CofeeLake something...)" before the update. 
Also gnome-shell cpu usage went significantly up now. 
How to bring it back?

sudo lspci -v output (relevant lines):

> ```
> VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
> Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620
> Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
> Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
> Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
> I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
> [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
> Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
> Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
> Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
> Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
> Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
> Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
> Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
> Kernel modules: i915
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, using steps 1 and 2 of the answer here:
[Ubuntu 18.04 not working with Intel Integrated Graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062967/ubuntu-18-04-not-working-with-intel-integrated-graphics)

It explains how to force Xorg to use intel drivers. 
It is still a mystery why it stopped using them in the first place.