# Ubuntu 18.04 won't work with i9 9900k integrated graphics

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, display-resolution, intel, gpu

I've had to remove my graphics card for some time and I've just connected my screen to the [Gigabyte Z390 AORUS Pro motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-rev-10#kf) output HDMI. But I can't change the monitor resolution to 2k (1440p), even though the Gigabyte spec states  the onboard graphics has [1 x HDMI port, supporting a maximum resolution of 4096x2160@30 Hz, Support for HDMI 1.4 version and HDCP 2.2](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-PRO-rev-10/sp#sp), and the [CPU's specs for UHD630 graphics onboard calls for 4096x2304](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i9-9900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html) .

I've followed steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1063032/596503) but it's not working, just changed the Login screen to 2k resolution.

Also I've copied the bin that describes [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/possible-missing-frmware-lib-firmware-i915/832528#832528), without any result.

Some outputs from related commands.

xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 720 x 576, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI1 connected primary 720x576+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 530mm x 300mm
   720x576       50.00* 
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

uname -a:

```
Linux cristian 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e30 (rev 0a)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e98
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a340 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a338 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a305 (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V (rev 10)
```

lshw | grep -A5 "Moth":

```
description: Motherboard
       product: Z390 AORUS PRO-CF
       vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       version: x.x
       serial: Default string
```

In my Windows partition, all works perfectly without any configuration so I suppose that all is OK in BIOS configuration.

Comment: You could try a newer kernel like `5.1`

Comment: How can I install that kernel?

Comment: See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade

Comment: Added extra info as @K7AAY requested

Comment: Any idea @K7AAY about mottherboard?

Comment: First, I would try different screen frequencies; what are you running the screen at now?  Then, since Gigabyte does not support Linux, I would try generating LiveUSB flash drives with Ubuntu 19.04 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop, Ubuntu Budgie 19.04 https://ubuntubudgie.org/downloads, Ubuntu MATE 19.04 https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/, Kubuntu 19.04 https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/, Lubuntu 19.04 https://lubuntu.me/downloads/, and Xubuntu 19.04 https://xubuntu.org/download/ to see if booting with a different kernel lets you get to 1440p.

Comment: Kernel 5.1 probably will not help. I'm using 5.1.16 and I'm having analogous problem with my iy-8750H and GTX1050Ti/intel 930. It doesn't see external hdmi with i915 card. However it worked smoothly with older Ubuntu (ex. original 18.04 without any updates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I installed Ubuntu Budgie 19.04 as @K7AAY recommended and all works fine.

Comment: So, it's something specific to Ubuntu 18.04 which uBudgie 19.04 does not use.