# Ubuntu not detecting integrated intel graphics card and reverts to llvmpipe

Tags: drivers, 18.04, xorg, intel-graphics, intel

Ubuntu 18.04 install (also seen on 16) is unable to detect integrated Intel graphics card (Intel Iris Plus). Using a Dell XPS 13 2-in-1 7390 the machine is unable to detect attached monitors, change resolutions, or adjust brightness.

There is a **dual boot Windows 10 partition**, which can access the integrated graphics card without issue and connects to attached monitors on boot. However, after deleting the W10 partition the behaviour is unchanged.

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
```

```
% uname -o
4.15.0-70-generic
```

```
$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-intel:
  Installed: 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1
  Candidate: 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1
  Version table:
 *** 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 500
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

```
$ lspci -v
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a52 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Dell Device 08b0
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
 Memory at 603d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
 Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
 [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
```

[System details, graphics displayed ass llvmpipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbB9y.png)

I have tried purging `nux-tools` to remove a leftover file that interfered with gnome as detailed in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/1768610).

Further, [this fix for intel integrated graphics cards](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062967/ubuntu-18-04-not-working-with-intel-integrated-graphics) also produced no results.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to upgrade the kernel to an officially supported HWE kernel.

You can do it by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Reboot to apply.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me.. thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the same graphics card in a Dell Inspiron 5593, I solved the problem of the brightness updating the kernel to the latest version.

You can easily update the Kernel with [ukuu](https://vitux.com/update-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-through-ukuu/), it's totally safe, if you have problems with a newest Kernel, you just boot with an old Kernel and change the Kernel version again with ukuu.

If you find a solution to the llvmpipe problem, please write about it, I'm still looking for something.

Comment: There is no need to install a mainline kernel with non-free UKUU, if there is an officially supported upgrade path.

Comment: I was trying to do that wiith "sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04", but the Kernel was not updating further than 4.15.0.70, so I tried ukuu.

Comment: Now it installs the 5.0.