# Tearing issues Intel Iris plus surface laptop 3

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel, surface

I have a big tearing problem on my screen, even when using an external display

I'm using a Surface Laptop 3 with the surface kernel from [this github](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface) (the latest one)

I have tried [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062967/ubuntu-18-04-not-working-with-intel-integrated-graphics/1063032#1063032) who didn't work

I have read somewhere that by executing this i should have a response but nothing outputs :
`grep -A29 Chipsets /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

i have version i915 of intel drivers and when adding `/ect/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` it does weird things on my screen like something is wrong so i always have to delete it afterwards

I've been trying to fix this for a month moreless so i done a lot more things which i dont remember...

I know i'm not giving a lot of informations about my system but as i'm new to linux and posting questions in forums, i'm not sure what more i can send. Just tell me what informations to send and i'll do.
I'm sick of those tearings ...

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: i Use ubuntu 20.04.3  David

Comment: I fixed it by using Ubuntu Wayland thanks to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231441/ubuntu-screen-flickering/1250859#1250859) post [why is Wayland better](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11537/why-is-wayland-better)